# Literal Meta Stack Overflow Questions

Tags: discussion

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814849/overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long-while-loading-stata-d) pop up in my feed, and it made me think, how many questions on Stack Overflow pertain to the actual stack overflow errors?

Comment: Your question title doesn't match your question.

Comment: @TinyGiant, how so?

Comment: Because you're asking about Stack Overflow Exceptions, not "Meta Stack Overflow questions"

Comment: Arithmetic overflows and stack overflows are also quite different beasts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2,540 questions.

At least that's the number of questions tagged with the [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) tag. But as you can see from your example, not all questions about stack overflow errors have that tag.